# AOSP 7.1.1 speech recognizer availability

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-source

I've built the AOSP 7.1.1 and I've noticed in the emulator that in the Language and Input menu, on the Speech part only the Text to Speech item is available. So the voice input item is not present.
This makes me think that the speech recognizer is not present in AOSP. Still I would need an official confirmation.

Can you confirm my hypothesis ? Is there an official Google documentation related to this topic ? (I would prefer the official documentation as it is easier to refer to)

Edit: To be more clear, I am interested in the availability of the service itself - weather it is implemented or not in AOSP.

Additional info: I see that AOSP provides APIs to handle the speech recognition but no info on the availability of the services
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the Languages & Input menu is the same for AOSP and for Google implementation. Therefore one can't really assume anything from this comparison.

A deeper analysis must be performed and sadly the information is not easy to find.

Comment: I'm not going to set it yet as the right answer, as maybe somebody has a better insight.

Answer (score 1):

AOSP includes a [public abstract class RecognitionService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionService.html), but no concrete extension of this class. You could try to search for "extends RecognitionService" (e.g. on GitHub) for open source extensions. The only one known to me is [Kõnele](http://kaljurand.github.io/K6nele/about/), which offers two extensions.

Regarding a UI to the settings, starting with Android v6, the speech recognition menu is in a new location:

1. Go to: Settings -> Apps -> Configure apps (cogwheel icon) -> Assist & voice input
2. Set "Assist app" to "None" (or try something that is not "Google App")
3. "Voice input" lets you now choose and configure the speech recognition provider

I don't know of any discussion (official or otherwise) of why this was made so undiscoverable and illogical.

Comment: It seems that the Assistent App is already set to None. As I said we are talking about AOSP, therefore also my concern related to its unavailability.

Comment: AOSP has never included an _implementation_ of an assistant nor speech recognizer. But it includes a settings menu for these things, it's just in a different place now. Please clarify your question.